# JavaScript ArcGIS: Change style of Measurement widget 3D

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using Measurement widget from ArcGIS SDK for JavaScript: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Measurement.html

Everything works fine, however I would like to change the visual style of the widget to match the rest of the application.

In particular I would like to decreease width of the outline, colour and disable the lines that show on the same height where you are pointing at:
[image]

I've read the documenetation and there was no mention of being able to change the style of the widget whatsoever. Is this even possible to achieve when using Measurement widget?

Comment: Have you got a solution for this?

Comment: @MahmoudAdel Sadly no. I don't think it's possible since rendering for those lines is done in WebGL and I didn't find any way to configure it.